# iptables rules' weird behavior

Tags: iptables, vpn

I have a set of iptables rules (see below) whose purpose is to disallow traffic to go out of my machine when my VPN connection is abruptly lost or manually terminated:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please wait a moment......"
echo "Save original iptables. Apply new iptables rules"

iptables-save > /home/username/vpn/iptables.save

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j DROP --ctstate INVALID
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -s 123.123.123.123 -i eth0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED #ca1.conf
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -d 123.123.123.123 -o eth0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED #ca1.conf
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

The above iptables rules work on a machine running an Intel Haswell CPU (i7-4xxx series, quad-core, 8 threads) and a Haswell chipset (H87 series).

However they do not work on a machine running an Intel Ivy-Bridge CPU (i7-3xxx series, quad-core, 8 threads) and an Ivy-Bridge chipset (H77 series).

Could someone tell me why?

The OS that is being used is Debian Wheezy and the same HDD is used for the above experiment.

Comment: How do they 'not work'? Do you get an error message? If so, post it. Also, it is highly unlikely that the cpu or its chipset has anything to do with your firewall problem; more likely there's some other difference somewhere.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst: `Also, it is highly unlikely that the cpu or its chipset has anything to do with your firewall problem;` Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely to be related to the CPU chipset. It's more likely to be related to the NIC.

If you're sharing the same hard disk and OS installation between two different machines, the NIC will be different so the MAC for that NIC will be different. Therefore it will almost certainly be bound on configuration to `eth0` but to `eth1` on the other.

You can fix this on Wheezy by editing `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and ensuring that both generated rules name the interface as `eth0`. (Just make sure you don't ever try to have a single machine with both NICs.)

Here is the appropriate entry from my system. Your systems' MACs will be different. This line instructs `udevd` to give the NIC with MAC `00:0a:cd:20:aa:3f` the name `eth0`:

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0a:cd:20:aa:3f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help. `If you're sharing the same hard disk and OS installation between two different machines` That was what I did. It was an experiment.

Comment: `Therefore it will almost certainly be bound on configuration to eth0 but to eth1 on the other.` Are you saying that iptables rules firewall are bound to the MAC of an NIC? I didn't know that.

Comment: `You can fix this on Wheezy by editing /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and ensuring that both generated rules name the interface as eth0.` After changing the interface name of both generated rules to `eth0`, do I have to `sudo update-grub` or something?

Comment: `(Just make sure you don't ever try to have a single machine with both NICs.)` Why? What are the reasons?

Comment: @festivalofmusic because my suggestion requires naming both of them explicitly as `eth0`. And that can't work.

Comment: `And that can't work.` What do you mean?

Comment: @festivalofmusic you can't have two devices with the same name at the same time. Likewise you can't have two files with the same name in the same directory at the same time.

Comment: Here's my feedback on your recommendation to edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and change `NAME="eth1"` to `NAME="eth0"`.  I did as you recommended, rebooted my machine and the iptables rules as stated in my original post *seemed to work for a short while*. However after my router assigned a different internal IP address, for example, 192.168.1.27, the above iptables rules failed again. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @festivalofmusic please define "failed again".

Comment: `please define "failed again"`. Well, when I manually terminate my VPN connection, I am able to access websites despite the fact that the iptables rules are still active.

Comment: I think I may have solved the issue of "failed again". In my `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, there are 2 generated rules. I just comment out (ie. put a #) in front of the rule that has the MAC address that I do not need to use. Next I reboot my machine and yes the iptables rules in my original post seem to work again, *for now at least.*